# How to achieve face detection using web camera

Tags: face-detection

How should I create face detection web application which capture photo and save when face comes in-front of camera.
Which technology currently available to achieve this.
Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a wonderful solution called tracking.js ([You can find it here](https://github.com/wesbos/HTML5-Face-Detection)). It's simple and wonderful.

Here's an example of how I use it in my code:

```
var trackerTask;
var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');

tracker.setInitialScale(4);
tracker.setStepSize(2);
tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);
trackerTask = tracking.track('#vid', tracker, { camera: true })

tracker.on('track', function (event) {
    // Do stuff when face was detected
});

// To stop tracking:
setTimeout(function () {
      trackerTask.stop();
}, 500);
```

In the above example, replace `#vid` with your HTML5 `<video>` element.